# Configure xsl to append a text to a html tag element

Tags: html, xml, xslt

```html
<presentation>
   <rootText>
    <firstChild>
     <b>Question</b>
     <br></br>
     <br></br>Sub Question<br></br>
     <br></br>
    </firstChild>
   </rootText>
   ...
</presentation>
```

Here is the xsl

```
    <xsl:template match="presentation">
    <div class="question">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="rootText"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
```

I want the output as below

```
' <div class="question">
     <b>1  Question</b>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>Sub Question<br></br>
    <br></br>
</div>`
```

I have to modify **Question** to **1 Question**. The questions will not be ordered all the time so the input xml will not contain question number. I am getting the random question number(qnum) but being stuck on how to modify **Question** to **1 Question**.Any idea ?

Comment: Should all `Question` texts be prefixed with the same number `1` or do you want a numbered list? As the target with `div` looks like HTML, why don't you transform to an ordered list `ol` if you want to number questions.

Comment: No. Question number will be a random number and cannot come with xml, So am unable to figure out a way to append the question number with question.It should be like `{QNUM} Question` where QNUM will be any random number.

Comment: No. Question number will be a random number and cannot come with xml, So am unable to figure out a way to append the question number with question.It should be like `{QNUM} Question` where QNUM will be any random number. the target is html  and it should  be' <div class="question">
         <b>1  Question</b>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>Sub Question<br></br>
  <br></br>
    </div>`. Edited the actual question.

Comment: Where exactly are you "getting the random question number"? Which XSLT processor and which version of XSLT can you use?

Comment: `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">` I will get question Number from a service, which I used in XSL as `<xsl:text>{QNUM}</xsl:text>`

Comment: Is it possible to configure xsl to update the `<b>Question<b>` with `<b>anyString Question</b>` (Here anyString is "1").  If so, how to do it?

Comment: Can you share some additional children details for `<rootText>`? Need to know whether the child node names are same or different.

Comment: There are no other childnode for <rootText>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might help you with your problem. Just adjust your 'random number' you want to have. At least this should give you the output you described.

```
<xsl:template match="presentation">
    <div class="question">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::b) + 1"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```